# Generate custom submission ID and download the data in a predesigned pdf template in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pdf-generation, form-submit, contact-form-7, wordpress-database

I am trying to make a form that has the following 2 features:

1. The form has a dropdown menu (eg. with values "Apple", "Orange", and "Grapes"). On submission, the form should be able to generate and pass a submission that is specific to the values selected in the dropdown menu. Eg.: If "Apple" is selected, on submission should give an id like "A1101", and the next "Apple" submission should give "A1102" (incremented by 1). The same should go with the other 2 options where they generate their own submission IDs which increment by 1.
2. The second necessity is that the user should be able to download his/her submission as a pdf shortly. I already have designed a pdf template. I just want the data to be populated wherever it is to be populated. The pdf should also contain the submission ID generated.

I tried many plugins for this, but none of them works along with the others. I am also not experienced to code any requirement in WordPress.